# CMD,DevCon and Visual Fox Pro

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, visual-foxpro

I made a .bat file using DevCon for restarting a device and when run it works.
When i try to run the same file in VFP form using the run command on click it says that DevCon is not recognized.

! cmd /c "C:\Windows\System32\restart.bat"

! "C:\Windows\System32\restart.bat"

I've tried making Sistem32 as a starting path and starting default and it does not work either way. It seems like CMD gets confused in the process. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Would help to see what is in the restart.bat file.

Comment: its a simple line devcon restart "some device"

Comment: Then why not specify the whole path to the devcon executable in your batch file.

Comment: still not working like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would instead try using ShellExecute API. ie:

```
#Define SW_HIDE             0
#Define SW_NORMAL           1
#Define SW_SHOWMINIMIZED    2
#Define SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED    3

Local lcResult
lcResult = ShellExec('C:\Windows\System32\restart.bat', '', 'C:\Windows\System32', SW_NORMAL)
If !Empty(m.lcResult) && error
    Messagebox(m.lcResult)
Endif

Function ShellExec
    Lparameters tcExecutable,tcParams,tcWorkingDir,tnShowType,tcOperation

    Declare Long ShellExecute In "shell32.dll" ;
        long HWnd, String lpszOp, ;
        string lpszFile, String lpszParams, ;
        string lpszDir, Long nShowCmd
    tcOperation  = Iif(Empty(m.tcOperation), 'Open', m.tcOperation)
    tcExecutable = Iif(Empty(m.tcExecutable), '', m.tcExecutable)
    tcParams     = Iif(Empty(m.tcParams), '', m.tcParams)
    tcWorkingDir = Iif(Empty(m.tcWorkingDir), '', m.tcWorkingDir)
    tnShowType   = Iif(Type('m.tnShowType') # 'N', SW_SHOWNORMAL, m.tnShowType)
    Local lnResult, lcError
    lcError = ''
    lnResult = ShellExecute(0,m.tcOperation,m.tcExecutable,m.tcParams,m.tcWorkingDir,m.tnShowType)
    If !( m.lnResult > 32 ) && Error
        lcError = GetShExecErrorMsg(m.lnResult)
    Endif
    Return m.lcError
Endfunc

Function GetShExecErrorMsg
    Lparameters tnErrNum
    Local Array aErrors[1]
    Local lcMessage, lcErrors,lnErrors,ix

    TEXT to m.lcErrors noshow
0,The operating system is out of memory or resources. \n
2,The specified file was not found. \n
3,The specified path was not found. \n
11,The .exe file is invalid (non-Win32® .exe or error in .exe image). \n
5,The operating system denied access to the specified file.  \n
27,The file name association is incomplete or invalid. \n
30,The DDE transaction could not be completed because
other DDE transactions were being processed. \n
29,The DDE transaction failed. \n
28,The DDE transaction could not be completed because the request timed out. \n
32,The specified dynamic-link library was not found.  \n
31,There is no application associated with the given file name extension.
This error will also be returned if you attempt to print a file that is not printable. \n
8,There was not enough memory to complete the operation. \n
26,A sharing violation occurred. \n
    ENDTEXT
    Clear
    lnErrors = Alines(aErrors,m.lcErrors,.T.,'\n')
    For ix=1 To m.lnErrors
        If ( Val(Chrtran(Left(aErrors[m.ix],;
                At(',',aErrors[m.ix])-1),Chr(13)+Chr(10),'')) = m.tnErrNum )
            lcMessage = Substr(aErrors[m.ix],At(',',aErrors[m.ix])+1)
            Exit
        Endif
    Endfor
    If Empty(m.lcMessage)
        lcMessage = 'An unspecified error occurred.'
    Endif
    Return m.lcMessage
Endfunc
```

Comment: tried it and it looks like bleh. ill read more about shell execute and will modify to my needs if its working ill let you know

Comment: looks like this does the trick thank you for the advice, with a little search about it ive managed to make it work
DECLARE INTEGER ShellExecute IN shell32.dll ; 
  INTEGER hndWin, ; 
  STRING cAction, ; 
  STRING cFileName, ; 
  STRING cParams, ;  
  STRING cDir, ; 
  INTEGER nShowWin
ShellExecute(0,"open","Batch Files\COMChanger2.bat","","",0)
MESSAGEBOX("See if its ok)